# Is there a way to create a custom task that can restart Apache httpd server?

Tags: apache, unix, jenkins, httpd.conf

is there a way to create a custom task to restart apache server and invoke that task using a Jenkins job? 
Presently I'm restarting it by running ./apachestop.sh and ./apachestart.sh on the terminal.

Comment: Yes. This is possible. Where exactly are you strugeling?

Comment: I'm currently running the following commands in my Jenkins job:      
cd /opt/jws-3.0/httpd/sbin
bash apachestop.sh
bash apachestart.sh
executing these over ssh communicator

Comment: Why are you unhappy with the current solution?

Comment: While using that it's waiting for credentials. I couldn't send those by Jenkins. That's making it wait for the password triggering the execution timeout exception. So I want to create a shell script file with the restart command and the credentials.

Comment: help me out if there is a way to pass the password in shell script file